# Replace symbol + and - with (+) and (-) only if they begin a string

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

```
df$X <- gsub("[+]", "(+)", df$X)
df$X<- gsub("[-]", "(-)", df$X)
```

These two commands replace all + and - with (+) (-) in my column even though I just want the change if it starts the cell.

Comment: Please include `dput(df)` in your question.

Comment: Try `gsub("^[+]", "(+)", x)`  The `^` is the start of string anchor.

Comment: This is a really great regex resource: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
 df$X <- gsub('^\\+', '(+)',df$X)
```

and

```
 gsub('^\\-', '(-)',df$X)
```

Another option is using `gsubfn` to do this in a single step

```
 library(gsubfn)
 gsubfn("^[+-]", list(`+` = "(+)", `-` = "(-)"), df$X)
 #[1] "(+)234x"    "ab+234"     "(+)cf+43"   "(-)234+49"  "abc-23"    
 #[6] "(-)23ab-34"
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(X = c("+234x", "ab+234", "+cf+43", "-234+49", 
 "abc-23", "-23ab-34")), .Names = "X", row.names = c(NA, -6L),
 class =   "data.frame")
```

Comment: oops.  beat me to it.

Comment: My vengeance will come :)

Answer (score 2):

This* works:

```
df$X2 <- ifelse(regexpr("\\+", df$X)==1 | regexpr("\\-", df$X)==1, paste0("(",
  substr(df$X, 1, 1), ")", substr(df$X, 2, nchar(df$X))), df$X)
```

*Apologies for posting malfunctioning versions before.

Comment: I misunderstood what he wanted and thought it was supposed to remove it. Will fix now. Sorry to keep wasting your time.